# How to create a rounded layout containing Imageview and a textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create a framelayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView. How can I create a rounded layout so that they are shown as in the image. I tried adding round shape to the background of layout but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Is that an image of what you currently have, or what you want to achieve?

Comment: This image is what I want to achieve.

Comment: To get reflection of the image try this  [Reflection of image](http://glorious-arvind.blogspot.in/2012/11/reflection-image-of-imageview-in-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have one class that does the same work, check this one for your reference add this class inside the package and use this
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

```
public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    if (b == null) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


    if(bitmap ==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor),
                (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

and use this type of XML for design

```
<com.packagename.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/odd_bubble"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/index"
    />
```

Comment: This is only rounding the ImageView. Textview should also come inside imageview and with rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ArcLibrary](https://github.com/stelladk/ArcLibrary)   to achieve something like this:

[image]

```
   <com.stelladk.arclib.ArcLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:ArcType="inner"
        app:ArcRadius="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scenery">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Change"
            android:background="@color/semiwhite"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </com.stelladk.arclib.ArcLayout>
```

Comment: Very useful, this helped me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view and inside custom view's `onDraw` use `canvas.drawText()` to place the text. Now create a new class extending `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and use the above custom view class and RoundedImageView class as inner classes. Now inflate the 2 views inside the parent class. You can now get the rounded image as well as text below it.

FYI : You have to pass appropriate params to the `drawText()` method so that it is aligned in the required position